Draw the angle graphically
Hi everyone (sorry for the "unclear" title), I'm having trouble graphically representing the point of this:
A stone is thrown from the top of a tower with $h = 50\text{m}$ and with a velocity of magnitude equal to $v_0 = 18 \text{m/s}$ and an inclined direction of $\theta = 50°$, upward, from the horizontal plane.
Find: The angle formed between the trajectory of the stone and the horizontal plane at the point of impact. 

[Neglect air resistance.]

$v_x$ is the horizontal component of the final velocity, constant;
$v_y$ is the vertical component of the final velocity;
$v$ is the resulting speed at the moment of impact;
$\theta_1$ is the impact angle

I searched vaguely on the internet and I think this formula should be used: $$\tan (\theta_1) = \frac{|v_y|}{v_x}$$
I can't understand graphically how to arrive at this formula (relating to the situation of the exercise above), if anyone could help me I would appreciate it very much :).

Hi, exercise questions are off-topic here.

@VincentThacker Sorry :(, I wasn't aware of that tag.

Why not just draw $\vec{v}$ ; vx and vy $
